# Droid RAZR MAXX HD and 13.04

Tags: 13.04, android

I recently re-installed 13.04 on my laptop (old partition crashed, pretty sure my hard drive is on the way out). I was using 12.04 previously, and had all but given up any home of getting my new phone, a droid razr maxx hd, to properly communicate with the OS, since it doesn't have the mass usb option, only mtp. I had heard that after upgrading to 13.04 everything would work natively, however this has not been the case. After plugging in my phone all that happens is I get a file system screen with windows driver install files (.exe's and all that jazz). If I switch it to ptp mode it recognizes it as a camera, but still no luck with MTP. Has anyone gotten a droid razr maxx hd to connect successfully with their 13.04 installation? If so, some help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried both Go-mtp and WINE (using motorola device manager.exe) with a rooted device. Motorola has neglected to provide the drivers for linux, which is a problem (https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481). Mounting an SD card via usb will not work either. I contacted motorola and they said they do not provide any drivers for linux, nor do they plan on providing them in the future. They actually said "You may have to check Linux if they can supply the driver"... I think we are S.O.L. - unless there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually able to get this to work today.  First, be sure that you have the following line in your the files

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
and
/etc/udev/rules.d/52-mtp.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Then run

sudo service udev restart

On your Droid, go to Settings => Developer options and enable USB debugging.

Plug your phone in via USB cable, and it should work.

Comment: USB debugging mode helped for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried several ways of mounting the phone as a device with only partial success.  I could get it to mount in Ubuntu to transfer pictures but not music.  I tried in Windows and ran into issues with drivers not properly installing.  Finally stumbled on the work-around:

Install google-musicmanager:

`sudo apt-get install google-musicmanager`

and start it from the terminal:

`google-musicmanager`

Chrome opens a new tab as a result. Then register for an account.  A "standard" account is free and permits you to store 20,000 of your songs in the Google cloud.  For $10/month you can store, I think, an unlimited amount of music as well as get music from Google.

One of the options I chose was to automatically upload any new music put into my ~/Music folder to the cloud.  Right now it's busy doing the initial upload (uploads are slow) and will probably finish in the wee hours of the morning tomorrow.

On my new Droid Razr Maxx HD the Google Music player automatically syncs to the music in my cloud storage.  I'm letting all of that happen via WiFi so I don't get excess data charges.  And so the music gets transferred.

I wish it was like my old phone.  That one appeared as a USB drive on the desktop when I plugged it in.  Then it was just drag and drop, unmount, and done.  Much simpler.  Oh well, the solution to the problem turned out to be free.